# Changing bibliography style does not change output

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm trying to change my bibliographystyle from plain to abbrv, but adding

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
```

does not change the output after recompiling. Any ideas where I could be making a mistake?

Comment: Are you using `latex` + `bibtex` + `latex` + `latex`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `abbrv` is the same of `plain`, only with more compact labels.

Comment: Thanks sigur - I wrongly assumed my editor would take care of the latex + bibtex business.